# Azure Mobile Apps - POST to table with foreign key "Bad Request" 400 error

Tags: entity-framework, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm hoping this is a simple question. I've created an Azure Mobile Apps project based upon the sample ToDo project, adding my own tables/data objects. The problem I'm having is adding/POSTing records to a table that has a foreign key relationship to another. The following is my Employee table data object:

```
public class Employee : EntityData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
}
```

...and this is my EmployeeType data object:

```
public class EmployeeType : EntityData
{
    public string EmpType { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

The virtual EmployeeType property in the Employee class was necessary, I believe, to create the relationship with the EmployeeType table when using EF Code First to create the tables in the database. (At least, that's what I understand, and it worked) I am able to insert records from my Xamarin client app into the EmployeeType table using the InsertAsync method, but I receive a "Bad Request" 400 error when trying to insert into the Employee table.

I've looked around quite a bit for solutions, but everything refers to Azure Mobile Services and not Apps. If need be, I can update this question with my client side model classes (I'm on my PC now and don't have access to the Xamarin Studio project on my Mac). For reference, these classes are pretty much the same as the data objects - just each property is decorated with the JsonProperty attribute, except the virtual property outlined in the service. And for completeness, I did try adding that property to the client object and it still threw the "Bad Request" 400 error.

Thanks for any direction you can offer me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is happening when trying to map the foreign key. Are you specifying all of the fields for employee type?  I recommend that you do the following:

1. Use Fiddler or attach a delegating handler to your client to see what the outgoing request looks like. Update your comment with the JSON body. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#log-outgoing-requests-in-managed-client-xamarin-windows.
2. Attach a debugger to your server project. You can do this while running locally or after your solution is deployed to Azure, but you'll have better performance if you run locally. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#remote-debugging-net-server-sdk.

I suspect that the problem is that EmployeeType ends up being null in your deserialized object, and then Entity Framework rejects the DB insert.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get more information from the bad request? Try adding this to the table controller

```
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        controllerContext.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
    }
```